# Convert .XLS TO CSV

Tags: linux, bash, shell, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have an xls file which I want to convert to CSV with delimiter. `;`

When I type this command from my repertoire

```
. xls for i in *; do libreoffice --headless --unaccept=accept-string --convert-to csv "$i"; done
```

it returns a file with the delimiter `","`

example:

```
"foo", "tati"
```

instead of

```
toto; tati
```

My question: is there no option for delimiter `;` for libreoffice?

OS Debian 7.5

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please format your question a little bit better? For example you could use code tags when you insert pieces of code inside your question. So it'll be easier for other users to read and understand what you're asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to simply post-process your file with sed if you can't find a LibreOffice solution. For example if your datafile from the conversion is `out.csv` and it contains the quotes and commas you would like to remove and change to semi-colons, you can do:

```
sed -i 's/["]//g' out.csv    # strips all double-quotes
sed -i 's/[,]/;/g' out.csv  # convert all commas to semi-colons
```

Answer (score 1):

If the answer turns out to be no, you can use tr to change commas into semi-colons, but this
assumes that neither appears in your data itself, so it's not a general solution.

See this similar question on the libreoffice website:

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/21916/cli-convert-ods-to-csv-with-semicolon-as-delimiter/